# Code in bashrc doesn't work

Tags: bash, grep, find

The code below **doesn't** work in bashrc but works in terminal with other arguments null.

```
search () {
        find $1 -type f | egrep '(.$2|.$3|.$4|.$5|.$6|.$7|.$8|.$9|.$10)'
}
```

Comment: The code _by itself_ won't do anything.  It's a function declaration.  Unless invoked, it's not supposed to do anything.

Comment: Did you use single quotes at the prompt? They are preventing the parameters from expanding; `egrep` is getting the literal text `$2`, etc. as its pattern.

Comment: Yes is a function. But the find line, replaced with arguments works in terminal with quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
search() {
  find "$1" -type f \( -true \
    -o -name "*$2*" \
    -o -name "*$3*" \
    -o -name "*$4*" \
    -o -name "*$5*" \
    -o -name "*$6*" \
    -o -name "*$7*" \
    -o -name "*$8*" \
    -o -name "*$9*" \
    -o -name "*$10*" \
  \)
}
```

1. As @chepner points out, the *single* quotes prevent the parameters from expanding. Use double quotes.
2. The `egrep` will create a line-based match result, which is less precise than the above. It's also slower.

If the above statements are not exactly what you need, keep in mind GNU find has regular expression predicates in addition to -name's pattern matching. There's no need to pipe to `grep`. You can expand the above function to take an unlimited number of arguments by constructing the arguments to `find`, such as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127303/5377).

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I needed a function to search a type of file (.mp3|.flac|.jpeg). But I solved. Unfortunately I can't post now because I new user.

Comment: this code will fail if user provides less than 10 arguments (as $n will be empty, thus find will look for `**` on those empty args ... matching anything). Do a while loop to construc the find statement, and *then* run it.

Comment: @OlivierDulac As would OP's code. I described how to construct the args in my [other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127303/5377), linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that the egrep get the literal text `$2` instead of argument. I solved with this code:

```
search-type () {
  case "$#" in
       1) echo "Missing arguments";;
       2) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2')';;
       3) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3')';;
       4) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4')';;
       5) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5')';;
       6) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5'|.'$6')';;
       7) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5'|.'$6'|.'$7')';;
       8) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5'|.'$6'|.'$7'|.'$8')';;
       9) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5'|.'$6'|.'$7'|.'$8'|.'$9')';;
      10) find $1 -type f | egrep '(.'$2'|.'$3'|.'$4'|.'$5'|.'$6'|.'$7'|.'$8'|.'$9'|.'$10')';;
      11) echo "Many arguments";;
  esac;
}
```

The @kojiro code doesn't work.

Is it possible to simplify this code with regex?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I change the code for the something more **simple** and **clear**; and works with any quantity of parameters.

```
search-type() {
    # Flags
    flag=0
    fld=1
    for x in "$@"
    do
        # The first parameter is the directory; ignored!
        if [ $fld = 1 ]; then
            fld=0
        else
            # Verify if have more than one file
            if [ $flag = 0 ]; then
                cmd='-name '$x
                flag=1
            else
                cmd+=' -o -name '$x
            fi
        fi
    done
    find $1 -type f $cmd;
}
```